# Subtract milliseconds from Time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a logdata file with an end time, and the operation duration specified in milliseconds. I would like to subtract the duration from the end time, to get when the operation started. How can I do this?

The columns are as follows:

```
|EndTime   |ElapsedTime|Logmessage|
|01:00:41.5|        412|Operation2|
|01:00:41.6|        260|Operation3|
|01:00:42.0|       1520|Operation1|
```

And what I want is this:

```
|StartTime |EndTime   |ElapsedTime|Logmessage|
|01:00:41.1|01:00:41.5|        412|Operation2|
|01:00:41.4|01:00:41.6|        260|Operation3|
|01:00:40.5|01:00:42.0|       1520|Operation1|
```

So that it's clear that operation 1, while being logged after operation 2 and 3, actually started first.

I've tried to simply subtract the `Elapsed` time column from the `EndTime` column.
I've tried to use the `Time` command:

```
Time(0;0;[ElapsedTime]/1000)
```

but `Time` apparently disregards milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as ElapsedTime is always an integer less than 32768,

```
TIME(0;0;[ElapsedTime])/1000
```

should work.  (I assume semicolons normally work for you in functions. 
On my machine, I would say `TIME(0,0,[ElapsedTime])/1000`, using commas.)

Warning: the “**Second**(s)” parameter to `TIME()` must be between 0 and 32767. 
If you ever have a duration greater than 32767 milliseconds
(i.e., 32.767 seconds), the above will fail. 
If that's a possibility, or if ElapsedTime could have a fractional part
(e.g., 412.867) — or could be negative — then Máté’s answer will work better.

Comment: Ah, I had the divisor inside the parenthesis. Thank you.

Comment: Your approach made perfect sense.  You had no way of knowing that the `TIME()` function rounds the **Second(s)** value down to the next lower integer (whole number) — it isn’t even documented.

Answer (score 2):

In excel days address stored as integers and hours and minutes are as fractions. Try this:
`EndTime-ElapsedTime/(24*60*60*1000)`